Series representation of $\frac{\cosh(\eta)}{\cosh(\eta) - \cos(\xi)}$
I stumbled on the following expression: $$\frac{\cosh(\eta)}{\cosh(\eta) - \cos(\xi)} = \coth(\eta)\left(1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^N e^{-\eta n}\cos n\xi\right)$$
How I pass from the LHS to the RHS? The intervals are $-\pi\leq\xi\leq\pi$, $-\infty<\eta<\infty$.
